# Get the password of a Protected Post in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, phpmailer

I am working on a WordPress theme, and I would like an author to send an email to someone when a Protected Custom Post is published.

**How to get the password of a Protected Post in functions.php?**

I already created a metabox field (for the e-mail) and I am using `PHPMailer()` in my functions.php file. The function works to get the name and the URL of the post, but I now need to send the password by email...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password is stored unencrypted in the column `post_password` of `wp_posts` table.

It's just a matter of:

```php
$the_post = get_post( PUT_YOUR_POST_ID_NUMBER );
echo $the_post->post_password;
```

Comment: That is clearly what I needed, thanks! I didn't think that it was unencrypted, this is also good to know.

If it can help someone else who searched for the same things, all the returned fields by get_post() can be found [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post#Return).

Comment: Use `var_dump( $post );` to inspect it. Sometimes, when testing, adding a `die();` after the dump is helpful too.

Comment: How to right has it to check match with cookie page protected by password?

Answer (score 1):

If you have set up a custom meta field for the value you wish to send you can just grab it with get_post_custom():

```
$custom = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );
```

Then you can access the meta value by its key from $custom like so:

```
$custom['keyofmetafield']
```

EDIT: Additionally I believe there is a core function the_post_password() if you're trying to get the password used to protect the page - but you mentioned saving something in a meta field so I wasn't sure.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_password/#source

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I am not looking for a custom meta value, but for the value of the default way to protect a post with a password (you know, when the visibility is "password protected").

Comment: EDIT : Yeah that was it. Your source really helped me, thanks!